# how to make a table unlocked within transaction block

Tags: sql-server, transaction

I am using SQL Server 2008.  I have several stored procedures that process different reports.  Each stored procedure makes use of `Begin Transaction' and 'Commit Transaction`, using the default isolation level.

Everything works fine since the target tables use by these stored procedures are different for each stored procedure, except that all stored procedures call another common stored procedure to write log messages into the `SPLog` table.   I need the `SPLog` table to be available to all stored procedures, and not to be locked by any stored procedure. The table is designed so that each message has a column indicating which stored procedure it belongs to.

The problem is the `SPLog` table is locked once a stored procedure is ran, causing other stored procedures to wait until the first stored procedure commits.  How can I allow `INSERTs` into this `SPLog` table by concurrent stored procedures from within a `TRANSACTION` block?

Below is the pseudo code of these stored procedures:

Stored Procedure SP

```
Begin Transaction

 business logic....perform operation A on dedicated tables
    call common SP to insert a message row to SPLOG table (for common use)
 business logic....perform operation B on dedicated tables
    call common SP to insert a message row to SPLOG table (for common use)
 ....
Commit Trasaction
```

All stored procedures have similar pseudo code. Appending rows to `SPLOG` table should be allowed at any time.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: btw there shouldn't be any reason to prevent many concurrent transaction from *inserting* new log entries into a log table. Normally, inserts do not block other inserts. You must be doing something that explicitly blocks the logging.

Comment: It doesn't block other inserts into the same log table. But it blocks reading of the inserted records while still within the transaction code block of stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do it outside of the transaction

For example: Spool the data in a table variable which don't participate in transactions and write once at the end (after commit). Or use Service Broker to decouple log writes.

Any logging otherwise is subject to the transaction semantics eg locks, can be rolled back etc

Comment: thanks for your comments. I understand to save the step message in memory and get written to the lgo table at the end after commit at one go. But this can't fullfil the requirments. Each step of SP could take quite long time, I want the step message be available for users or some client web application to poll and display, so that users know which step the SP has run into. In another words, step message written into the SPLog table is requsted to be real time. I don't know how to use servcie broker, also don't understand "use Service Broker to decouple log writes." Can you possible show a exam

Comment: The rest gets cut off, but it's "example, thanks" ... @JianguangFang can you login on this site with the same OpenID you used to sign in on [so]?

Comment: @JianguangFang: Do want this to persist this in a log, or is it just for notification/polling purposes by other processes?

Comment: I need persist the message in a log table (for back tracking and verifying) as well as for notification/polling purposes by other applications. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: Hi gbn,
I need persist the message in a log table (for back tracking and verifying) as well as for notification/polling purposes by other applications. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: @Jianguang: see [Logging messages during a transaction](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2010/10/17/logging-messages-during-a-transaction.aspx) for an example of using SSB to decouple logging. That article shows how to actually achieve logging in a parallel transition (logging stay even if your procedure rolls back), which may or may not be desired.

Comment: Hi gbn, thanks for your valued advice. Although I don't use service broker, I found to use NOLOCK or Read Uncommitted to query from the SPlog table. This satisfies my request to read each step message of SP without waiting for SP to be completed(committed or rollback). BTW, can u also help me for this tougher question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904695/how-to-push-data-or-message-from-sql-server-to-web-application

Comment: Hi gbn, thanks for your valued advice. Although I don't use service broker, I found to use NOLOCK or Read Uncommitted to query from the SPlog table. This satisfies my request to read each step message of SP without waiting for SP to be completed(committed or rollback). BTW, can u also help me for this tougher question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904695/how-to-push-data-or-message-from-sql-server-to-web-application